# While changing orientation in mobile need to close popup window

Tags: php, jquery

Making few changes in desktop website to work in mobile(Landscape mode only), if users change the orientation to Portrait then will display a message to change orientation. It works as expected.

Challenging part is while showing javascript alert or dropdown options, if user change the orientation not getting the "Orientation change message" instead of that whole site is displayed.

Can we do this without reloading the page by checking orientation using "mobile jquery" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use orientationchange method for check orientation mode.

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function(event){
  alert("Orientation is: " + event.orientation);
});
```